# Removing redundant information, difficult SQL query

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table in the format:

```
`users`
- id
- views
- email
```

Here are some entries I have:

```
`id`        `email`                 `likes`
9570800   -anroy@gmail.com      888
5355388   -Btionz@gmail.com     3042
8610061   -cmendez@naia.org         450
6189810   -dancox_photog@yahoo.co.uk 0
6625684   -david.d.@gmail.com        0
16841675  -david.d.@gmail.com        40
9716153   -david.d.@gmail.com        0
9716353                              0
97161453                             0
```

I want to `DELETE` all entries that have a duplicate email and keep the entry with the highest `likes`. For example, in the above, the duplicates for `-david.d.@gmail.com`  would mean `6625684` and `9716153` would both be deleted, and `16841675` would be kept (since it has the most likes out of the duplicates.

In addition, if the `email` is blank (`''` or `NULL`), ignore it / do not delete it.

How would I accomplish this query?

Comment: nice page to play and test with MySQL sqls: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2440d/1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
DELETE lesser FROM MyTable AS greater JOIN MyTable AS lesser USING (email)
WHERE greater.email <> '' AND greater.likes > lesser.likes;
```

Comment: you might also want to add `and greater.email is not null`

Comment: @Jeshurun, good idea, but that's handled by the join.  Email can never be null if `greater.email=lesser.email`.

Answer (score 0):

```
DELETE FROM Users WHERE NOT userid in (
    SELECT userid FROM Users u 
        INNER JOIN (SELECT userid,max(likes) ml FROM Users GROUP BY userid) u2
           ON u.userid = u2.userid AND u.likes = u2.ml
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

First, be careful. Review the list of potential deletions:

```
SELECT * FROM users
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT email, max(likes) max_likes FROM users GROUP BY email HAVING count(*) > 1
) keep ON users.email = keep.email
WHERE users.likes <> keep.max_likes
```

Then, if that looks okay to you, substitute `SELECT *` with `DELETE users`

Comment: Where is the reference to max(likes) ?

Comment: The subquery, `SELECT email, max(likes) max_likes FROM users GROUP BY email HAVING count(*) > 1`, returns the list of rows to **keep**.

Comment: `max(likes) max_likes` names the column and aggregates the maximum number of likes for that email address.